# How to marge current line with previous line in txt file based on some condition in python?

Tags: python, text, python-re

My input text file is :

[image]

My expected output text file is :
[image]

Here we need to merge line 3 and 4 based on the condition that line 4 is not starting with "[" using python

Comment: You should maybe include some reproducible data to allow it easier for other users to help you and provide you with a working answer. Is there any code which you have already attempted?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through lines, keep previous line in a variable.

If current line doesn't start with `[`, add it to the previous line.

Else save previous line to file and update it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something along the following lines:

```
lines = []

with open("file_in.txt") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        if line.startswith("["):
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            lines[-1] += line  # append to last line

with open("file_out.txt", "w") as f_out:
     f_out.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is not solved. my "file_in.txt" is the same as "file_out.txt"

Comment: That should work just fine. Just use the same file name in both cases.

Comment: I think the problem is with "\n"

Comment: try replacing `lines[-1] += line` with `lines[-1][:-1] += line`
If it works, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, \n at the end of each line keeps the file same. "\n" should be removed before merging lines. This should solve the problem.

```
lines = []

with open("file_in.txt") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        if line.startswith("["):
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            lines[-1] = lines[-1][:-1]
            lines[-1] += line  # append to last line

with open("file_out.txt", "w") as f_out:
     f_out.writelines(lines)
```